# Php remove array of array?

Tags: arrays

Hi I have displaying array for below result.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => test1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => test2
        )
```

)

I want to delete the element ( => Array )

```
Array
(
    [0] => test1
    [1] => test2
    [2] => test3
    [3] => test4
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have pushed an array inside another array and  [0] => Array is not an element, It is showing that at 0th index of array, There is another associative array.

Use **array_push** function if you're using php or add code snippet, So that Me or someone can give you exact code which you're looking for